# Supressing oracle banner

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus, oracle12c

Is there a way to avoid banner text that sqlplus shows on connecting.
e.g.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

I want to goto prompt. Just want to avoid banner, rest every things is required, like feed back etc.

My requirement is for both 11g and 12c Oracle.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - that is **the** anwser, so please post it as such.

Comment: If you want an interactive session - since you do want the prompt - is the banner really a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `sqlplus -s ...`

However, it also suppress the prompt `SQL>`. I don't know a solution which does both: suppressing the banner but showing the prompt.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I have tried it. My requirement is such that I invoke SQLPLUS with credentials and @mysql.sql to execute scripts. The output file generated contains this banner information as well besides other my required information like. ... Table Created etc. I compare generated file with  already existing results to verify health of results/scripts. When working with different versions of Oracle, get different banners/info. So want to suppress to have one standard result.

Comment: @Ikram - using `-s` won't suppress feedback. If you're running a script do you really want to see the prompt, or the commands being run? If you really do, maybe you need to spool the output to a log file, instead of redirecting the output (as you are presumably doing now)?

Comment: Thanks Alex, using -S is hanging my bash terminal.

Comment: Thanks Alex, using -S is hanging my bash terminal.

 e.g. sqlplus -S  hr/hr@orcl   will hang terminal and I have to kill forcefully. Can you guide what setting I need to make to have -S work for me

Note: I  am uisng CentOS 6x and CentOS 7x OS 64 bit. Without this -S option it logins fine.

Comment: Are you sure? Maybe it just looks like hanging because you don't get any prompt - as by purpose.

Comment: Thanks again.  -S worked fine for me. On terminal it was hanging but when used inside my test file, it worked . Thanks again. Issue resolved.

Comment: sqlplus -S is not hanging - just type 'exit'